# Skills to learn to avoid age discrimination (specifically .net)

Tags: .net, language-agnostic, programming-languages

I am an asp.net programmer and I am getting up there in my age. I wanted to know, from your experience, what skills (please be as specific as possible) would you focus on (.net or generic), what skills would you make sure you are razor sharp on, in order to avoid age discrimination?

I have heard from a few recruiters that I have "alot" of experience. I don't know if that would mean that I am too old.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here...  If the employer is bent on discriminating based on age, then not sure how skills will help.  On the other hand, if you're asking how to improve your skills to make you a more attractive candidate in general, there are good questions here, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364/what-is-the-single-most-effective-thing-you-did-to-improve-your-programming-skill  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site

Comment: Well, I am interested more in how to stay in demand within the job market, when given that age discrimination is common, and it would take about 6 weeks for some company to get an H1B guy from India to do that job cheaper. So a developer should have skills that would beat that H1B candidates value. I hope I am clear. There is not much I can do if an employer is discriminating against me, but if I have the skills and experience, then someone else would hire me.

Comment: just try to keep up with the technology bro. You will always have a job

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say market yourself as an Architect (application, database whatever your desire). To some that is a fancy title, but research what an architect is, and zero in on it. I have never seen an architect position get off shored or be run by a 25yr old. The only catch is, you have to back up the "I am an architect and I know my stuff"

Answer (score 4):

Be on a few failing projects. Learn which patterns (technical, corporate, personal) lead to success, and which ones lead to failure. Share your wisdom with the bright, young, naive team building the Twitter-killer.